# How will I serialize complex Django Models to json?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a REST service in my django application using djangoRestframework [django-rest](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

I have model Student in MyModels.py which is has follows,

```
from django.db import models

class Student(object) :
    def __init__(self,first_name,middle_name,last_name,subject_list=None):
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.last_name = last_name
            self.middle_name = middle_name
            self.subject_list = subject_list

class Subject(object) :
    def __init__(self,name):
            self.name = name
```

The below code is from views.py

```
def getStudentList(request):
my_list = []
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Alajandro",middle_name="Santana",last_name="Gonzales"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Timothy",middle_name="Carlos",last_name="Robins"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Nathan",middle_name="Nick",last_name="Mathews"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="John",middle_name="Nelson",last_name="Kennedy"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Tom",middle_name="Kenny",last_name="Cruise"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Jerry",middle_name="Sanvile",last_name="McGuire"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Jason",middle_name="San",last_name="Statham"))

student_list = []

for student in my_list:
    student_ser = rest.StudentSerialize(student)
    student_list.append(student_ser.data.copy())

json = JSONRenderer().render(student_list)
return HttpResponse(json)
```

The url mapping in urls.py is

```
 url(r'^studentList/', views.getStudentList),
```

The response is get from URL
    http://127.0.0.1:8083/studentList/

is

```
[{"first_name":"Alajandro","middle_name":"Santana","last_name":"Gonzales"},{"first_name":"Timothy","middle_name":"Carlos","last_name":"Robins"},{"first_name":"Nathan","middle_name":"Nick","last_name":"Mathews"},{"first_name":"John","middle_name":"Nelson","last_name":"Kennedy"},{"first_name":"Tom","middle_name":"Kenny","last_name":"Cruise"},{"first_name":"Jerry","middle_name":"Sanvile","last_name":"McGuire"},{"first_name":"Jason","middle_name":"San","last_name":"Statham"}]
```

Now If I am interested in also passing subjects in the json. I am trying to do is one-to-many relationship between student and subjects. i.e one student can have many subjects.

So i am expecting this json as an output

```
 [{
      "name" : "Tom",
      "subject_list" : [{..},{},{},....]
  },{},{}...]
```

For this above I have done following changes in code

my MyModel.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Student(object) :

    def __init__(self,first_name,middle_name,last_name,subject_list=None):
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.last_name = last_name
            self.middle_name = middle_name
            if subject_list is None:
                    self.subject_list = subject_list

class Subject(object) :
    def __init__(self,name):
            self.name = name
```

My MyREST.py contains

```
from MyModels import Student
from MyModels import Subject
from rest_framework import serializers


class StudentSerialize(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    middle_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My views.py contains

```
def get_student_list(request):

my_list = []
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Alajandro",middle_name="Santana",last_name="Gonzales"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Timothy",middle_name="Carlos",last_name="Robins"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Nathan",middle_name="Nick",last_name="Mathews"))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="John",middle_name="Nelson",last_name="Kennedy"))


subject_list = []
subject_list.append(Subject(name="Computer Science"))
subject_list.append(Subject(name="Physics"))
subject_list.append(Subject(name="Chemistry"))

my_list.append(Student(first_name="Jason",middle_name="San",last_name="Statham",subject_list=subject_list))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Tom",middle_name="Kenny",last_name="Cruise",subject_list=subject_list))
my_list.append(Student(first_name="Jerry",middle_name="Sanvile",last_name="McGuire",subject_list=subject_list))

student_list = []
for student in my_list:
    student_ser = rest.StudentSerialize(student)
    student_list.append(student_ser.data.copy())


json = JSONRenderer().render(student_list)
return HttpResponse(json)
```

And in urls.py I added

```
 url(r'^student_list/', views.get_student_list),
```

Now If I hit the URL I still get json output as

```
[{"first_name":"Alajandro","middle_name":"Santana","last_name":"Gonzales"},{"first_name":"Timothy","middle_name":"Carlos","last_name":"Robins"},{"first_name":"Nathan","middle_name":"Nick","last_name":"Mathews"},{"first_name":"John","middle_name":"Nelson","last_name":"Kennedy"},{"first_name":"Jason","middle_name":"San","last_name":"Statham"},{"first_name":"Tom","middle_name":"Kenny","last_name":"Cruise"},{"first_name":"Jerry","middle_name":"Sanvile","last_name":"McGuire"}]
```

But I don't get the subjects.

What I should add in class SudentSerialize so that if I set subject_list in object of student, I will get json of Student an the property subject_list will have subject json array.

Comment: Your code looks very peculiar. Your models are just plain classes which do not extend the django Model class, but you import yet the needed module. I don't see also any custom persistence to a database. What purpose are you following with this approach?

Comment: In your `StudentSerializer` you have to add the property `subject_list`. I think here it would be appropriate to use `ListField`.

Comment: As mentioned by @cezar above, you don't seem to be harnessing the benefits of Django or REST Framework. What is your game for the long run, if you do not mind sharing?

Comment: I just want an api in django framework which will convert list of student objects to array of json's , and converting student object to respective json, and converting complex object relation like composition, like Student has many subjects to json like json of student has array of subject json's. Can you please tell me what API should I use. Wether I can use django-rest-framework in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use nested Relationships to do this job :

Here is an example :

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]

class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    middle_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    # nested relationship
    subjects = SubjectSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'middle_name',
            'subjects'
        ]
```

Read [Django Rest Framework - Nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects).
The documentation should cover everything you need to know about this.

Please also take some time to run the 6 steps of the [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). It will give you hints about how to use DRF.